# Unable to test with mockito for inheritance method

Tags: java, spring, mocking, mockito, jmockit

I have the below code

```
class A {
    public int someMethod(int someParameters....) {
        ........// some implementation 
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public int someMethodFromB(int someParameters....) {
        ........// some implementation 
        return someMethod(someParameters....);
    }
}
```

I am writing test for class B for someMethodFromB and I want to mock someMethod which we are returning the value. How can I test the code as B is extending A.

I have tried the below 2 approaches but did not work out

```
@Test
public void testSomeMethodFromB() throws Exception {
      ContextData contextData = mock(ContextData.class);

      SomeObject obj = mock(SomeObject.class);

      B b = spy(new B());

      doReturn(obj).when(b).someMethod(obj, contextData, false);

      Assert.assertNotNull(b.someMethodFromB(someAnotherObj, contextData, Optional.of("someString")));

    }
```

and this one too

```
@Mock
private A a;

@InjectMock
private B b;

@Before
public void setUp() {
   MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testSomeMethodFromB() throws Exception {
     ContextData contextData = mock(ContextData.class);

     SomeObject obj = mock(SomeObject.class);

     when(a.someMethod(obj, contextData, false)).thenReturn(obj);

     b.someMethodFromB(someAnotherObj, contextData, Optional.of("someString"));

    }
```

Comment: What does _did not work out_ mean?  Based on the mismatch of method parameter types, does this even compile?

Comment: Alternatively does B need to extend A? could B use composition and have a member of A?

Comment: So you are mocking the object that you are testing? What is the expectation of such a test?

Comment: Class B IS_A Class A, so the `someMethod` is a method from Class B, it's inherited, so you are trying to mock a method from the class that is under test, which is weird. Like @scigs suggested, maybe you should swap to composition.

Answer (score 0):

might be me but this:

```
@Test
public void testSomeMethodFromB() throws Exception {
     ContextData contextData = mock(ContextData.class);

     SomeObject obj = mock(SomeObject.class);

     when(a.someMethod(obj, contextData, false)).thenReturn(obj);

     b.someMethodFromB(someAnotherObj, contextData, Optional.of("someString"));

    }
```

makes no sense to me, what are SomeObject.class and SomeAnotherObj? SomeAnotherObj gets passed as a parameter but is never defined?
You mock SomeObject.class but never mention it, is it just something you need for test, unrelated to the question?
I think you could do something like this:

```
public class BTest {

    @Mock
    private A a;
    @InjectMocks
    private B b; 

    @Test
    public void testSomeMethodFromB() {

        when(a.someMethod(something)).thenReturn(something);


        int result = b.someMethodFromB(something);

        Assert.assertEquals(expected, result);
    }
```

again, maybe im mistaken, its been a long day at work, but i dont quite understand the examples
Good luck anyhow!

Answer (score 0):

I tried a simplified version of what you are trying to do and it worked:

```
public class A {

    public int someMethod(int value) {
        return 2 * value;
    }
}
```

```
class B extends A {
  public int someMethodFromB(int value) {
    return someMethod(value);
  }
}
```

```
class BTest {

  @Test
   void myTest() {
     B spyB = spy(new B());
    
     doReturn(5).when(spyB).someMethod(8);

     assertEquals(5, spyB.someMethodFromB(8));
  }
}
```

So my guess is that the parameters that you are passing to `someMethod` in the test are not exactly the same the code is receiving when calling it.

For example if I change the parameter of `someMethod` to `6`, the test fails, because when the code runs it receives the value `8` and not `6`, so the spy does not apply:

```
  @Test
   void myTest() {
    B spyB = Mockito.spy(new B());

    Mockito.doReturn(5).when(spyB).someMethod(6);

    assertEquals(5, spyB.someMethodFromB(8));
  }
```

Debug your test and check what are the parameters when `someMethod` will be called to make sure they are the ones you are passing in the test at the `doReturn...` call.